# Renew Let's Encrypt SSL certificate - Plesk

Tags: ssl, plesk

I am referring to the Let's Encrypt Free SSL certificate.

How to renew the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate in the Plesk panel?

I have checked many articles but not found a single resolution regarding my issue. So I am looking for someone who can help me to answer my question.

Comment: Look for a "renew" or "reissue" button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to renew the Let's Encrypt certificate for your **Plesk server**, navigatie to
*Tools & Settings* > *SSL/TLS Certificates* and click the *Let's Encrypt* button and then the *Renew* button.

If you want renew the Let's Encrypt certificate for a particular domain, navigate the domain in Plesk and click the **Let's Encrypt** icon or the **SSL it!** icon (if you have the SSL it! extension installed).